# How to redefine JS function with regard to closure?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, closures

I try to redefine Class.method, it uses a function from a closure.
Modified version I provided currently is not working as it uses e() function which is not directly accessible from Global namespace.
Is there a way to make modified version work without editing anything else?

```
function() {
    function e(a, b, c) {
    // e body
    }
    Class.method = function(a, b, c, d) {
        // method body
        return new e(a, b, c)
    }
}

//Modified version (Not working)
Class.method = function(a, b, c, d) {
            // method body
        alert("I'm modified!");
        return new e(a, b, c)
    }
```

Comment: It depends on the modification

If you just want to add logging, you can wrap it

Answer (score 1):

No way whatsoever with your current code - functions are function-scoped, and therefore `e` isn't accessible outside of the anonymous function. You need to either move your modified method inside the anonymous function (and name the function so it can be called) or move `e` outside of the function.